# How to update Linux servers?

Tags: centos, package-management, upgrade

I am planning to update a bunch of servers. Currently, I get an email every month, on the updates that are available per servers. I don't want to check ~100 updates per server, is there a way to automatically check if the update is a critical update or not?

At the moment,  I check if the updates are security related like so:

```
yum --security check-update
```

If it says:

> No packages needed for security; 100 packages available

I know that at least there aren't any security updates.

How can I automate the process of installing only critical updates?

Answer (score 0):

CentOS (assuming you are on it) does not keep separate repositories for critical and other (e.g. enhancements) updates. But do check [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10021) solution from Red Hat.

Answer (score -1):

Could you elaborate on what "critical" means in your context?

If you cannot do this in a manner a programme would understand there most likely is no such command to help you right away.

EDIT:
For critical="needs a reboot of the server" there's actually only a kernel-upgrade that forces this (which can be circumvented for HA systems to some extend using [special tools](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2851028/linux/four-ways-linux-is-headed-for-no-downtime-kernel-patching.html)). So you could just upgrade the kernel-package (+dependencies) to the latest version.

Comment: This is just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: In a sense it's both. As this question might not have an answer depending on the authors definition of "critical".

Comment: Anything that cause downtime. Meaning reboot of server(kernel).

Comment: @blade19899 - yes, of course. check if the update is for your kernel package.

Comment: Keep in mind that restarting a service (like apache, mysqld, ...) might also cause downtime. Do you consider this as critical as well?

Comment: Yeah, I actually do. But, that cause like a seconds of downtime, right?

Comment: @Jack - possibly - but updating the package doesnt require you to restart the service.